# Spyder 4.1.4 crashes on MacBook Pro and Anaconda

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder

I am using a MacBook Pro, and I am new to Python and Anaconda.  I am trying to use Spyder as an IDE, and every time I open it, it crashes.  I am running Anaconda from July 2020 with Spyder 4.1.4. I have uninstalled Anaconda, reinstalled it, and rebooted my computer.  Spyder was working fine yesterday, and when I started my computer this morning, it just crashes.  I have tried to downgrade to Spyder 4.1.3, and Anaconda just spins.  Any help would be appreciated.  Thank you.

Comment: I am getting the following error when launching Spyder...```json
[
    {
        "level": "WARNING",
        "line": 176,
        "message": "Line 0. Exception - Expecting ',' delimiter: line 1 column 279 (char 278)",
        "method": "load_log",
        "module": "logs",
        "path": "/Users/marksingleton/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/anaconda_navigator/utils/logs.py",
        "time": "2020-08-25 14:16:29,383"
    }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to find some documentation online to do “spyder --reset” after rebooting my computer, and it worked.  Thanks!